# Prolog permutation predicate using insertion of elements

Tags: recursion, prolog, logic

I am trying to write a predicate `permutation/2` so that it is true if and only if both arguments are list, one a permutation of the other. To do this, I've written the two helper predicates `delete/3` and `insert/3`. The first is true if and only if the third argument is the second argument, both lists, with the first instance of the element in the first argument removed. The second is true if and only if the third argument equals the second argument with the first argument (element) inserted.

```
delete(X,[X|T],T). % Base case, element equals head.
delete(X,[A|B],[A|C]) :- delete(X,B,C). % Else, repeat for the tail.

insert(X,[],[X]). % Base case.
insert(X,[H|T],B) :- delete(H,B,U), insert(X,T,U). % Delete all elements from B.

permutation([],[]). % Base case.
permutation([H|T],P) :- permutation(Q,T), insert(H,Q,P). % P a permutation of T, H inserted.
```

My idea is that the query

```
?- insert(A,B,X).
```

For given A, B should return all ways of instantiating X so that it equals the list B with the element A added somewhere. However, it does not do this:

```
?- insert(3,[1,2],X).
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
X = [1, 3, 2] ;
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

I think this is because of the way I defined the predicate, checking if the list in the third argument minus every element of the list in the second argument equals the list containing only the first argument, rather than defining it constructively, but I am having a hard time solving this problem another way. The permutation predicate should then check if the list in its second argument is a permutation recursively, by checking if P is a permutation of the tail of the first list with the head randomly inserted. Help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you can ask question: "why is my definition of `insert/3` broken?"?

Comment: You can see lists.pl in https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl/blob/master/library/lists.pl where you find many "textbook" predicates. I first found such predicates in "The Art of Prolog" which is a textbook by Sterling and Shapiro. Maybe you are allowed to read textbooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `insert/3` and `delete/3` is the same predicate and it is found in textbooks as `select/3`. It is also in standard library, for example in SWI-Prolog you can find it as `select/3`. You can use it to *insert* or *delete*, just change the position of the list as necessary.

Delete "b" from "abc":

```
?- select(b, [a,b,c], X).
X = [a, c] ;
false.
```

Insert "b" in "ac" in any position:

```
?- select(b, X, [a,c]).
X = [b, a, c] ;
X = [a, b, c] ;
X = [a, c, b] ;
false.
```

It is defined exactly as you did define `delete/3`, if you see the source of lists.pl in SWI-Prolog which is open source you will see it.

```
select(X, [X|Tail], Tail).
select(Elem, [Head|Tail], [Head|Rest]) :-
    select(Elem, Tail, Rest).
```

But now you can define permutation just like you described. Because I find also this in the same source file lists.pl I just copy the source here, and it is ok because it is open source:

```
perm([], []).
perm(List, [First|Perm]) :-
    select(First, List, Rest),
    perm(Rest, Perm).
```

I use `lists:perm` because it is "private" but it is not private it is just not exported:

```
?- lists:perm([a,b,c], P).
P = [a, b, c] ;
P = [a, c, b] ;
P = [b, a, c] ;
P = [b, c, a] ;
P = [c, a, b] ;
P = [c, b, a] ;
false.

?- lists:perm([a,b,c], [b,a,c]).
true ;
false.
```

I have just one message and it is: read the textbook and read the source because it helps you learn much faster.

Comment: We are required to write these predicates ourselves, that is why I have not used the built-in predicates. I wrote insert based on my delete predicate so it's good to see this is considered a good definition. However, neither insert or permutation work as I expect them to. So thanks, but unfortunately your answer does not solve my problem!

Comment: @Kermit but what is your problem really? These predicates are defined and described in textbooks decades ago when I was not born and I am not even very young anymore. So just take the book and read the code and learn. Or you can also ask questions on Stackoverflow and then say that your problem is not solved but what is the problem really?

Comment: I am not looking for just any solution, I am trying to understand why my solution does not work.

Comment: @Kermit But do you see that you cannot write "insert" based on "delete" because "insert" and "delete" in Prolog is the same thing? Maybe you can define `insert(X, Y, Z) :- delete(X, Z, Y).`

Comment: @Kermit it does not work because you defined it wrong. If you study the definition of `select/3` or of your own `delete/3` and you understand why you can "insert" using `delete` (which why "delete" is not a good name, and "insert" is not a good name! but `select` is a bit better name) than maybe you understand your error? Or maybe not?

Comment: @Kermit And which is also why I write in comment to your original question "Maybe you can ask question: "why is my definition of insert/3 broken?"?". Because if you want to know why your definition of `insert/3` is broken than you should ask "why is my definition of `insert/3` broken" and not "how to write permutation using insertion". Or maybe not.

Comment: I see what you mean now by `insert(X, Y, Z) :- delete(X, Z, Y).`, it's silly I missed that myself. With regards to the wording, yes, you may be right. It stems from me not being sure if this is even the right approach to solving the problem using insert.

Comment: @Kermit I don't know if I am right, I just try to help. I also must do Prolog in university and my experience is not so easy. But I can struggle and define predicates myself or I can read a book and learn and then I have more time, and I have a drink and instead of asking "how to define permutation in Prolog" I maybe ask question "sometimes I am happy; and sometimes I am sad. Why is that?" This is called "soul" like the music but I prefer funk or jazz or even techno.