# Prolog recursive list shuffling

Tags: prolog

Revising for a prolog exam and working through past papers that we don't have answers for and I've got stuck halfway through a problem and I was really hoping for some help!

The question:
Write a predicate `permute(Xs, Ys)` that scrambles the elements of the list Xs to obtain the scrambled list Ys.

The query `?- permute([1,2,3], Ys).` should succeed six times and give the following answers:

```
Ys = [1,2,3]
Ys = [2,1,3]
Ys = [2,3,1]
Ys = [1,3,2]
Ys = [3,1,2]
Ys = [3,2,1]
```

though not necessarily in that order.

We're advised to use a predicate we've already made, and so far I have this:

```
insert([], Y, [Y]).
insert([H|T], Y, [Y, H|T]).
insert([H|T], Y, [H|T2]) :- insert(T, Y, T2).

permute([], []).
permute([H|T], X) :- insert(T, H, X).
```

When I query it I only get half as many as I should, and I can't work out to switch the order of the list.

```
?- permute([1,2,3], Ys).
Ys = [1,2,3],
Ys = [2,1,3],
Ys = [2,3,1].
```

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43096468/812818) useful.

Comment: @DanielLyons thank you that has helped some, and if I run perm([1,2,3], P) of the code in the answer it works, but I'm really struggling to "translate" (for want of a better word) the select/3 predicate into my insert/3 predicate which I have to use

Comment: Don't think of predicates as functions. Predicates define relationships between arguments. So `insert/3` and `select/3` are completely equivalent to each other, just with re-arrangement of arguments.

Comment: @lurker really sorry if I'm being obtuse, but if the `select/3` in `perm(List, [First|Perm]) :- select(First, List, Rest), perm(Rest, Perm).` is the same as my `insert/3`, I just can't work out what the recursive call would be. I've trued rearranging and matching the arguments and failed miserably

Comment: Did you test your `insert/3` predicate on its own, independent of `permute/2`? If so, does it work correctly? My other comment was just that: `insert(ListWithoutX, X, ListWithX)` is the same as `select(X, ListWithX, ListWithoutX)` (as defined in the Prolog library). If properly implemented, their behavior should be the same.

Comment: A couple of other comments, you can get rid of `insert([], Y, [Y]).` and replace `insert([H|T], Y, [Y, H|T]).` with `insert(T, Y, [Y|T]).`. Also, your `permute/2` clause needs to be recursive: `permute([X|T], P) :- insert(PT, X, P), permute(T, PT).`. Your implementation only takes care of insertion of the head of the list to other positions in the list, as you can see from your results.

Comment: I tested `insert/3` and `insert([1, 2, 3], 4, X)` gives `X = [4,1,2,3]; X = [1,4,2,3]; X = [1,2,4,3]; X = [1,2,3,4].` If I use your `permute/2` with my insert it gives me `P = [1,2,3];` and then ERROR: Out of global stack

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a solution entirely based on `append/3`:

```
permute(XX, [B|YY]) :-
    append(AA,[B|CC],XX),  % remove random element B from XX
    append(AA,CC,DD),      % DD is XX without B
    permute(DD,YY).        % permute DD into YY
permute([],[]).
```

Simple to understand, but probably less efficient than the traditional implementation (altough the operating principle is exactly the same; read the comments) that has been already suggested.

Comment: Thank you, I've used to trace to follow this through to try and understand it and just feel like I'm missing something really key that I need to do to my insert or permute predicate that will get it to do what I want. I seem to be going round and round in circles a bit